# Exploratory Analysis - finding the most important factor

Tags: r, machine-learning, naive-bayes, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a dataset of 113 variables.  In exploratory analysis the first thing I want to know is what are the most important factors on  a single variable (revenue). I learned that naive Bayes would work, but I do not know how.

I am using `e1071` package and coded according to the example:

```
library(e1071)
data(iris)
classifier <- naiveBayes(iris[,1:4], iris[,5]) 
table(predict(classifier, iris[,-5]), iris[,5])
```

If you know any other algorithm that is not computationally expensive and suitable for exploratory analysis please let me know.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I realized that random forest algorithm is my answer. Importance function can help in finding the most important variable.

[random forest package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf)

Comment: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. We try to avoid [link-only answers](/stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) which are subject to link-rot and [may be deleted](/stats.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). As such this is more of a comment than an answer in its own right. If you're able, could you expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: More specifically, if a link to a package is the answer, the question is almost certainly off topic here.